# Model.find() calling a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I have 3 models user, micropost, like

I followed Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl
https://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book

Now I am adding new features and was trying to add a like button and after some changes now my micropost delete button doesn't work.

```
#micropost_controller   
def destroy
        Micropost.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to root_url
      end

#_micropost.html.erb
<%= link_to "delete", micropost, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                   title: micropost.content %>
```

Even though i am calling Micropost.find Active Record searches in likes table and gives the error as

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in MicropostsController#destroy
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: likes.micropost_id: SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."micropost_id" = ?
```

Similar thing happens when i try to delete a user. So basically whichever destroy i am trying to call it is redirected to like model

PS: the problem started after i executed

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("BEGIN TRANSACTION; END;")
```

as i was getting `BusyException: database is locked: commit transaction`

models

```
#like.rb
class Like < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :microposts, optional: true
    belongs_to :users, optional: true
    validates :src_user_id, presence: true
    validates :des_user_id, presence: true
    validates :post_id, presence: true
end


#micropost.rb
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 140 }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy

  # Returns microposts from the users being followed by the given user.
  def self.from_users_followed_by(user)
    followed_user_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                         WHERE follower_id = :user_id"
    where("user_id IN (#{followed_user_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id",
          user_id: user.id)
  end

  def self.search(search)
    where("content LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  end

end


#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: "follower_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :followed_users, through: :relationships, source: :followed
  has_many :reverse_relationships, foreign_key: "followed_id",
                                 class_name:  "Relationship",
                                 dependent:   :destroy
  has_many :followers, through: :reverse_relationships, source: :follower

  has_many :likes, foreign_key: "src_user_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :liked_by_users, through: :likes, source: :likes

  scope :starts_with, -> (name) { where("name like ?", "#{Example User}%")}

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_remember_token
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }, unless: Proc.new { |user| user.password.nil? }
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |user| user.password.nil? }
  validates :birthday, presence: true
  validate :email_verification, on: :update

end
```

Comment: can you show your models? how are your models associated? do you have callbacks?, something is trying to do something like "microposts.likes" or similar somewhere

Comment: just a second..

Comment: do you have the micropost_id column on your likes table?

Comment: i have a post_id in likes table

Comment: You have `belongs_to :microposts` and `belongs_to :users`, it should be singular, not plural. For that `belongs_to :micropost` association to work rails expects a `micropost_id` column on the likes table. Check the guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association. Rails is based on convention over configuration, for the "magic" to work you need to follow the conventions (or configure the proper names of things if it's not the convention)

Comment: If the micropost association is done via the "post_id" column, then tell that to rails `belongs_to :micropost, foreign_key: :post_id`

Comment: you'll have a similar problem with the `belongs_to :user` association, but it looks like you have two different users, not just one, you'll need two belongs_to associations

Comment: i changed and tried but still not working
but if i comment out `has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy in micropost.rb` it works

Comment: actually its just the `dependent: :destroy` part if i remove it it works fine

Comment: is there any way to have the dependent: :destroy and still make the code work?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not the find, is the destroy, it tries to destroy the associated like when you destroy a user or a micropost and it can't find it since you don't have the associations right

Comment: you have to fix your associations, follow the rails guide and compare your associations with it, you are not following the conventions

Comment: Ok Thanks, Let me try.

Comment: arieljuod thanks for the help, i have posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User
  has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
   # You never have to specify foreign key for indirect assocations
  has_many :likes, through: :microposts
end

class Micropost
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "post_id"
end


class Like
  # You must specify the foreign key if it cannot be derived from the name of the association
  # `belongs_to :micropost` will use micropost_id
  belongs_to :micropost, optional: true, foreign_key: "post_id"
  belongs_to :user # you have to add a `likes.user_id` column
end
```

Although I would really question if you want to use the same table/model for user likes and micropost likes. It really just makes things a lot more complicated and you end up with a table with a large number of null values. If this is part of the book I really wonder what the author was thinking as its a really bad design.

You can just set it up as:

```
# app/models/users/like.rb
# table name is users_likes
module Users
  class Like
    belongs_to :src_user, class_name: 'User', optional: false
    belongs_to :des_user, class_name: 'User', optional: false
  end
end

class User
   has_many :likes_as_src, 
     class_name: 'Users::Like',
     foreign_key: :src_user
   has_many :likes_as_des, 
     class_name: 'Users::Like',
     foreign_key: :src_user
end
```

---

```
# app/models/users/like.rb
# table name is microposts_likes
module Microposts
  class Like
    belongs_to :user, optional: false
    belongs_to :micropost, optional: false, foreign_key: 'post_id'
  end
end

class User
  has_many :micropost_likes, class_name: 'Microposts::Like'
  has_many :liked_microposts, through: :micropost_likes, source: :micropost
end
```

That gives you two simple join tables with non-nullable foreign keys and good indices. It also makes the validations very straight forward.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I was trying to do it somewhat like this. but the other one also worked. if you don't mind could you please tell me about some materials to learn this way of association, its very confusing in most of the materials. thanks

Comment: I don't think there is even a particular name for a join table that joins the same table twice. It's somewhat related to a self-join but not quite the same thing. I would just read the rails guides on associations a few times so that you understand the options.

Answer (score 1):

Correct associations would be

```
#user.rb

has_many :microposts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :likes, through: :microposts, foreign_key: "post_id"


#micropost.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: "post_id"


#like.rb
belongs_to :micropost, optional: true
```

After this, it works fine